# exact sequences on tikz?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I'm trying to "draw" an exact sequence with the code

```
\begin{tikzcd}
    \{0\}\arrow{r}{a}&A_1\arrow{r}{f_1}&A_2\arrow{r}{f_2}&\text{...}\arrow{r}{f_{k-1}}&A_k\arrow{r}{f_k}&...
\end{tikzcd}
```

But I get the following abomination

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: If I guess enough code to compile your code fragment, I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKR2Z.png

Comment: I fixed it by removing from a align environment. I wanted to put it the center of the page

Comment: @GrimmTroupe, do you need to use tikzcd? Why did you try it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: To center, place the tikzcd between `\[...\]`. Also, use `\cdots` not `...`.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{tikzcd}
    \{0\}\arrow{r}{a}&A_1\arrow{r}{f_1}&A_2\arrow{r}{f_2}&\text{...}\arrow{r}{f_{k-1}}&A_k\arrow{r}{f_k}&...
\end{tikzcd}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

However, running LaTeX on this example produces 26 error messages!

1. Never use `align` for a single equation
2. If you nest `tikzcd` inside an `align` environment (which should be rarely needed), use `ampersand replacement`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
\{0\}\arrow[r,"a"] &
A_1\arrow[r,"f_1"] &
A_2\arrow[r,"f_2"] &
\dotsb
\arrow[r,"f_{k-1}"] &
A_k\arrow[r,"f_k"] &
\dotsb
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
&\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
\{0\}\arrow[r,"a"] \&
A_1\arrow[r,"f_1"] \&
A_2\arrow[r,"f_2"] \&
\dotsb
\arrow[r,"f_{k-1}"] \&
A_k\arrow[r,"f_k"] \&
\dotsb
\end{tikzcd}
\\
&\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
\{0\}\arrow[r,"a"] \&
A_1\arrow[r,"f_1"] \&
A_2\arrow[r,"f_2"] \&
\dotsb
\arrow[r,"f_{k-1}"] \&
A_k\arrow[r,"f_k"] \&
\dotsb
\end{tikzcd}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Note `\dotsb` and the preferred syntax for arrows.

[image]